# send string from a fragment to a class (not activity)

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to send a string from a fragment to another class? However the class is not an activity, I searched for solutions but I got nothing :(
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "send a string to a class"? You can call a method on any class and send a String as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Make a newInstance() method in your fragment. When you're commit() the fragment send paramaters what you want.

```
public static SampleFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SampleFragment fragment = new SampleFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And then in your Fragment's onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}
```

If you're sending fragment to activity, you can do this with normal intent.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways for example a static variable for the string or put the string in the constructor of the class write a setter for it or save the String  to a file and read the file with your class
... be creative

666

Answer (score 0):

For communication between components you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/README.md) (Android-library). It is really easy to use (takes less than a minute to understand how it works) and is great in performance.